# Removing recessed lights for painting

Tags: painting, light-fixture, plaster

We've just had a new kitchen, and the ceiling has been re-skimmed.  I need to paint this, but we now have spotlights in the ceiling; see the picture below:

[image: Spotlight]

In order to get this off, I can see a small ring, which I can remove, and the bulb pops out, but the trim remains in place.  What's the technique for removing the trim (or is the best way to try and paint around these somehow)?

Comment: Try pulling straight down on the trim ring. Or remove the bulb and take a closer, flash picture of what you see inside there with the bulb out.

Comment: I tried that, but I'm nervous of pulling plaster off with it

Comment: They floated the skim coat with the ring in place????

Comment: Okay, I didn't realise this, but the ring does pull out, but it's on some kind of spring mechanism.  Thanks to everyone that commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, the one bulb that I started with does seem to be stuck, but for the rest, there's a spring loaded lever above the plaster; for future travellers, this is how I took it out for painting:

[image: Bulb1]
[image: Bulb2]
[image: Bulb3]